# Cannot assign None: "StaffMember.user" does not allow null values

Tags: python, django

Ok so here is the code, I will explain what I try to do at the bottom of the page. I am just starting out with python and django please keep that in mind.

Models.py (there is more in here but its not important):

```
STAFF_TYPES = (
    ('OG', _('Organizer')),
    ('MO', _('Moderator')),
    ('SC', _('Scanner'))
)

class StaffMember(models.Model):
    """
        Staff member class
    """

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('user'))
    staff_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=STAFF_TYPES,
        verbose_name=_('staff type')
    )
```

forms.py:

```
class StaffMemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(User.objects.all(), label=_('User'), required=False)
    username = forms.CharField(label=_('Username'), required=False)
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_('First name'), required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_('Last name'), required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_('Email'), required=False)

    def passwordRandom(string_length=10):
        random = str(uuid.uuid4())
        random = random.upper()
        random = random.replace("-", "")
        return random[0:string_length]

    class Meta:
        model = StaffMember
        fields = ('staff_type',)

    def clean(self):
        if self.errors:
            return self.cleaned_data

        super(StaffMemberForm, self).clean()
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        username = cleaned_data.get("username")
        first_name = cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        last_name = cleaned_data.get("last_name")
        email = cleaned_data.get("email")
        user = cleaned_data.get("user")
        staff_type = cleaned_data.get("staff_type")
        check = [username, user]
        if staff_type:
            if any(check) and not all(check):
                return cleaned_data
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('Choose a user from the dropdown OR make a new user'))

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if self.cleaned_data.get("user") is None:
            User.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
            User.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
            User.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
            User.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            User.password = self.passwordRandom(8)
            StaffMember.user = User
            User.save()
        else:
            StaffMember.user = self.cleaned_data.get("user")
        StaffMember.save()
```

Ok so essentially what I am trying to do here is create the option to either choose an existing user from the dropdown or create one by using the forms, therefore the fields can't be required because they can both be empty (not at the same time though).
So I want the form to save a new user and use that user to connect to the staffmember when they choose to make a new one. How would I do this because so far I'm only getting an error.

Thanks in advance,
Aaron

PS. Sorry for the messy code, just starting out as I stated before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new `User` object in your `save()` method

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    # Run the default save method, commit=False stops the
    # model saving to the db
    staff_member = super(StaffMemberForm, self).save(commit=False)

    if self.cleaned_data.get("user") is None:
        # Create a new User object
        user = User()
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.password = self.passwordRandom(8)

        # Save new user
        user.save()

        # Apply the new user to the staff_member object
        staff_member.user = user

    else:
        staff_member.user = self.cleaned_data.get("user")

    # If the form was expecting to save the StaffMember then save
    if commit:
        staff_member.save()

    return staff_member
```

*UPDATE: Modified code to reflect comments*

Comment: Quick edit: staff_member = user should be: staff_member.user = user and I 1 other mistake I made was not including a return statement in the save. Other than that thanks alot!

Comment: I've updated the code with your changes.  Happy to help.